# What is the right CodeIgniter debugging strategy

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the CodeIgniter ver. 2.1.4 and trying to be familiar with it using Lynda's online course 'Up and Running with PHP CodeIgniter'. But on the video 2.3 (3. Saving magazines using active records) I'm having an error `Class 'MY_Model' not found`. I'd try to avoid to bring all the code here or asking the community to track the error instead of me. I'd rather try to understand what is wrong by my self.

I tried to explore the PHP code from the very beginning (from /index.php) but it looks too complicated and time consuming way. Probably there (in CodeIgniter) are any rules to include the source files into the project? The file containing the missed class declaration is `/application/core/my_midel.php` and I didn't find the way how this file should be included.

Any thoughts and hints can be very useful as I'm a very newbie in CodeIgniter.

Comment: Can you post my_midel.php onto a http://phpfiddle.org/ so I can just take a quick look at it?

Comment: @Chitowns24 if I did everything right - here it goes: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sxq-297

Comment: Make sure that the file name is `MY_Model.php` **not** `my_midel.php`.    Also the file names are case-sensitive on Linux.

Comment: @HashemQolami You're right - the file name was low-case. But it's strange: in the original course materials the file name is the same: http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1392656417-clip-5kb.jpg. After I've changed the file name to MY_Model.php I have another weird error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` for line `$this->db->insert($this::DB_TABLE, $this);`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will fix it but in my Model code there is a constructor function right away after the initial declaration

```
    function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
```

It may also be worth it to see how you are calling the model and if you made any typos on naming conventions

If you are loading the model in a controller you have to do this to call it

```
$this->load->model('my_model');
$this->my_model->update();
```

I hope this helps